# $\frac {\pi} {1+\frac {\pi} {2+\frac {\pi} {3+\frac {\pi} {4+\frac {\pi} {\ddots}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

$$\cfrac \pi {1+\cfrac \pi {2+\cfrac \pi {3+\cfrac \pi {4+\cfrac {\pi} {\ddots}}}}}$$

I don't want a solution to this. I just want to know to begin ! I've been trying for almost an hour now. Thanks for the help

EDIT 1 :

Here is what I tried :

$f(n) = n + \frac {\pi} {f(n+1)}$

$f(n+1)(f(n)-n) = \pi$

$f(1)f(0)=\pi$

since, $\pi$ is the factor of two numbers. So one must be 1 and other must be $\pi.$

$f(2)(f(1)-1)=\pi$

If $f(1)=1$, then, $f(2)(1-1)=\pi$ which is impossible.

$So, f(0) = 1$ must be True!

Hence the answer is 1

Can someone please verify ? Thanks :)

Comment: Try clicking on some of the related questions down the right hand side of this page and see if any of those give you a hint

Comment: This should be a good starting point: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstant.html

Comment: It's clear where to begin: if you want to do continued fractions, read a book about continued fractions. Just to write something on paper and start calculating is not a reasonable method (unless you are Ramanujan).

Comment: Leonhard Euler demonstrated how to transform an infinite series into a continued fraction and how to transform a continued fraction into a series. A translation of this paper is online here: https://people.math.osu.edu/sinnott.1/ReadingClassics/continuedfractions.pdf

Comment: I have added an edit. This is what I could come up with.

Comment: I don't follow on the logic of $\pi$ being factorable.

Comment: I have used the fact that, if $\pi$ were to be represented as the product of two numbers, it could only be represented as $\pi = 1 \cdot \pi$

Comment: @KDboi what about $\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\pi} = \pi$?

Comment: @james.nixon Yupp ! Totally forgot about that case. I will have to think about some other way. Thanks :)

Comment: Hope I've got it right this time...$$\frac{2\sqrt\pi}{e^{2\sqrt\pi}-1}+\sqrt\pi=1+{\cfrac\pi{3+{\cfrac \pi{5+{\cfrac\pi{7+{\cfrac\pi{9+\ddots }}}}}}}}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt can you please add some link or source for that identity // also I am not sure how I can use it here. Thanks :)

Comment: It just looks really close to your problem.  It follows from the continued fraction of $e^{x/y}$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Transcendental_functions_and_numbers

Comment: I found this one while browsing the link by @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction

Comment: Ah yes... the result should be $$\frac{\pi~_0F_1(2;\pi)}{_0F_1(1;\pi)}=\cfrac \pi {1+\cfrac \pi {2+\cfrac \pi {3+\cfrac \pi {4+\cfrac {\pi} {\ddots}}}}}$$